# How we can know the blackberry secret in Pigeon room

Tags: rusty-lake-hotel

When in Rusty Lake Hotel we make attempt for Pigeon, we must to find black berry inside the prisoner small bird `by TORTURE` him!!! I did think this very unpleasant.. How we can know it must be to hurt this bird Six time to get to win?? Is hint given before in some where, of count to pull lever? Or must only cruel person know what way to win..

I have missed some where the hint from Mr owl and I wish knowing its place..

Comment: Am I come to wrong site?? Perhaps this game is not to be discussed here.. I see no other such  alike.. Please inform if it is mistaken!

Comment: Questions about Rusty Lake Hotel are acceptable here so long as they are on topic (see the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)).  However, this game seems include horror and dark humor, so if that makes you uncomfortable it may not be for you.

Comment: You speak true, thanks to you. To kill animal persons it is also dark but Mr Owl does tell us we must. Does some where he tell the small bird has this berry?? Or the toad does?? I have missed the hint and I wish knowing where is it..

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you edit this and provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

None of the secrets in *Rusty Lake: Hotel* have any clues leading to them. They are secrets, to reward people who explore beyond the puzzles necessary to complete the game.